# Split string into matrix vba

Tags: vba, matrix, split

I have 3 informations on a row and I can have multiple row selected. So what I'm looking for is a way to split a first time each row into an array.

That's what I'm doing here.
    line = Split(msg, ",")

Then I want to for every line to split info to obtain a matrix with first identifer the line and the second is the info

```
ReDim pro(Ubound(line),3)
For i = 0 To Ubound(line)
pro(i) = Split(ligne(i), "/")
Next
```

But It throw me a mismatch error so I don't know how to do it

for example :

I have this

msg1/1250/Description,msg2/1500/Description2,msg3,45656,Desctiption3

And finally have this :

pro(0,0) = msg1

pro(0,1) = 1250

pro (1,1) = 1500
etc ...

Thank you

Comment: Can you give more examples, without the `etc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strInput            As String

    Dim arrVals             As Variant
    Dim arrVar              As Variant
    Dim arrVar2             As Variant
    Dim arrResult           As Variant
    Dim lngCount            As Long: lngCount = 0

    strInput = "msg1/1250/Description,msg2/1500/Description2,msg3/45656/Desctiption3"
    arrVals = Split(strInput, ",")

    ReDim arrResult(UBound(arrVals), 1)

    For Each arrVar In arrVals

        arrVar2 = Split(arrVar, "/")
        arrResult(lngCount, 0) = arrVar2(0)
        arrResult(lngCount, 1) = arrVar2(1)
        lngCount = lngCount + 1

    Next arrVar

End Sub
```

That's the result:

[image]

As far as I did not see that you need a `DescriptionN` I have skipped it.

Comment: Thank you I think I will take your example in my program, I really appriciate

Answer (score 1):

Not optimal in any way, but it should give you a start:

```
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Line = "msg1/1250/Description,msg2/1500/Description2,msg3/45656/Desctiption3"
RowCount = UBound(Split(Line, ",")) + 1
ReDim pro(RowCount, 3)
For Each x In Split(Line, ",")
    j = 0
    For Each y In Split(x, "/")
        pro(i, j) = y
        j = j + 1
    Next y
    i = i + 1
Next x
```

Comment: If you remove the `+1` and change `ReDim pro (RowCount, 3)` to `ReDim pro (RowCount,2)` your solution would be nicer. Currently you have empty values in rows and columns in the matrix. But still good enough :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have initially as `pro` is called a "jagged array". You can use a "double-transpose" to transform it into a 2D array. But beware that it needs that all the "line arrays" be of the same size:

```
Function toMatrix(msg as string)
  Dim line: line = Split(msg, ",")
  ReDim pro(UBound(line))
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To UBound(line)
    pro(i) = Split(line(i), "/")
  Next

  ' transform array of arrays into a 2D array.  
  toMatrix = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(pro))
End Function

Sub Test
  Dim msg As String
  msg = "msg1/1250/Description,msg2/1500/Description2,msg3/45656/Desctiption3"
  Dim ar
  ar = toMatrix(msg) ' ar is now a 2D array
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't thought it was related to the type of my array and I wasn't even aware you could transpose array in order to transform them